# Mocking a python database query

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, mysql-python, python-unittest

I am trying to  test by  mocking  a database query, but receiving an error:

```
Asssertion error:AssertionError: Expected call: execute()
Not called
and create_table() not defined.
```

I want to `execute()` to be called and use `create_table()` to return response for asserting against pre-defined values.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask,g

@app.before_request
def before_request():
       g.db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='root', database='mysql')

def create_table():
    try:     
        cur = g.db.cursor() #here g is imported form Flask module
        cursor.execute ('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Man (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(40)')
        data = dict(Table='Man is created')
        resp = jsonify(data)
        cursor.close()
        return resp
```

test.py

```
  import unittest
  from app import *
  from mock import patch

  class Test(unittest.TestCase): 
  def test_create(self):
   with patch("app.g") as mock_g:
     mock_g.db.cursor()
     mock_g.execute.assert_called_with()
     resp = create_table()
     assertEqual(json, '{"Table":"Testmysql is created","Columns": ["id","name","email"]}')
```

What am I doing wrong?Can someone please tell me how to fix it

Comment: `mock_g.execute.assert_called_with()` will try to assert that you called execute with no arguments but you try to check it before actually calling execute, and besides that execute is not a method of mock_g it's a method of cursor. Also, you're not mocking databse connection, so it will still try to connect to the database and json in your test is not defined (unless you accidentally imported it from app) - and please don't use `import *` it's a bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add your changes before closing the cursor, or the execute won't occur. Try adding `cursor.commit()` before (or instead of) `cursor.close()`.

Comment: It did  not work that way also.I believe i am missing something in mocking  execute()